# How to clone a Plone portal?

Tags: plone, zope

I wonder what is the most efficient and functional way to clone a Plone portal (on the same server). Both copy & paste, and export & rename & import methods in ZMI don't work.

Comment: How does `copy & paste` fail for you? What are you trying to achieve with cloning the site?

Comment: Martijn: intended use is e.g. something like ZMI level portal snapshotting.. in order to test some changes, if one is afraid undo will be impossible. In many cases, on portal copy/paste, i get `Site Error, An error was encountered while publishing this resource, Error Type: AttributeError, Error Value: REQUEST`, last traceback item: `Module Products.PloneFormGen.content.formMailerAdapter, line 571, in _dreplace`

Comment: It is *far* easier to create a backup of the Data.fs than to clone the site in this way. :-)

Comment: Martijn Pieters: well, i want both the original and the cloned (backup) portal to be accessible to users, from some reasons.. pitty that Plone does not support such cloning..

Comment: You can bring up a separate server from the copy of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally we find the easiest way is to do a .zexp export and then a .zexp import. However this only works if the path of where you import the site is the same as where it was originally so works from moving between identical servers, not copying a site.

If you really really want to copy a site on the same zope instance you can't copy it directly.
You could export the settings via portal_setup and export the content via something like collective.jsonify or something similar.